# Windows 11 not showing Ubuntu as a booting option in its boot menu (Dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

**Windows 11 not showing Ubuntu as a booting option in the boot menu**

I installed Ubuntu in dual-boot along with Windows 11 and when I reentered into Win11, I can't boot into Ubuntu anymore. Win11 doesn't show Ubuntu as a booting option in its boot menu.
I can't access into Ubuntu 22.04 anymore. This has happened to me several times in other laptops as well (that one had multiboot with Win7).

The way you can reproduce the same issue is by downloading and installing Ubuntu's latest version and then logging in, setting up some demo files, and then restarting the system to enter into Windows again. Now you can't enter into Ubuntu again because Windows has done something to it maybe.

Comment: You'll need to (re)install grub. Grub will offer you the selection between windows and Ubuntu, the windows bootloader won't

Comment: Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Windows also may update UEFI which can reset UEFI settings. So any you changed may need change again. ReCheck UEFI &  Windows settings.

Comment: Windows should be installed first, then Ubuntu. If Windows is installed after Ubuntu Windows boot loader overwrites GRUB. I think better to install on separate drives.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Windows was pre-installed, then I installed Ubuntu. The way I have setup my partition is: I have created a separate partition of around 600MB for the GRUB and given 40~60GB to Ubuntu (I thought that would be adequate). I didn't install Ubuntu on "/" for in case the grub fails/misperforms, I could always get back to Windows and continue working.

Comment: Would it work for you to put GRUB on a flash drive and boot your installed Ubuntu from that? I have one computer set up that way.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron How does that work? I'm expecting a video about what you are talking about.

Comment: If you make a Full install Ubuntu 20.04 USB, then boot from it on the Windows 11 PC and in Terminal run `sudo update-grub` both Windows and Ubuntu 22.04 will be added to Ubuntu's USB boot menu. You can then select Windows or 22.04 when booting the USB. For Full install USB see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step. I showed Full install for Ubuntu 20.04 rather than 22.04 because Windows addition to GRUB has been slightly crippled in 22.04. The USB will boot in BIOS or in UEFI modes.